# opencart-3.0.3.2 & images with system url instead of url by domain

Tags: php, image, localhost, wamp, opencart

I have the machine on windows 10, wamp with alias, OC 3.0.3.2 and misunderstanding of how the network works from a programmer's point of view.

Uploaded image have a url like a "C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\sitename\image\catalog\goods\image.png", but should be like a "http://sitename/image/catalog/goods/image.png" and as a result of which image is not showed.

After installing OC I delete all default categories and product, made new category and create the product. Uploaded product image (i suspected not only images of product) is not show.

Moreover in admin panel path in left bottom corner of browser is correct, but image in time select it not showing too.
[problem illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLEbL.png)

I tryed:

- add in ./config.php and ./admin/config.php

```
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://startshop/image/');
```

- change ./catalog/model/tool/image.php
  by

```
if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
    return $this->config->get('config_ssl') . 'image/' . $image_new; 
} else {
    return $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $image_new;
}
```

to

```
if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
    return 'HTTP_IMAGE' . $new_image;  // return 'http://startshop' . $new_image; try too
} else {
    return 'HTTP_IMAGE' . $new_image;  // return 'http://startshop' . $new_image; try too
}
```

but how i understood this not work in OC_3

Also I tryed turn on .htaccess thinking what alias work is not correct, but nothing...

OC errors:

```
2023-03-09 14:19:15 - PHP Unknown:  The Twig_Autoloader class is deprecated since version 1.21 and will be removed in 2.0. Use Composer instead. in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\system\library\template\Twig\Autoloader.php on line 12
2023-03-09 14:19:15 - PHP Unknown:  Using Twig_Autoloader is deprecated since version 1.21. Use Composer instead. in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\system\library\template\Twig\Autoloader.php on line 30
2023-03-09 14:19:15 - PHP Unknown:  Using Twig_Autoloader is deprecated since version 1.21. Use Composer instead. in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\system\library\template\Twig\Autoloader.php on line 30
2023-03-09 14:19:15 - PHP Unknown:  Using Twig_Autoloader is deprecated since version 1.21. Use Composer instead. in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\system\library\template\Twig\Autoloader.php on line 30
2023-03-09 14:19:15 - PHP Unknown:  Using Twig_Autoloader is deprecated since version 1.21. Use Composer instead. in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\system\library\template\Twig\Autoloader.php on line 30
2023-03-09 15:40:57 - PHP Warning:  googleshopping\Googleshopping::integer(): Argument #1 ($product_id) must be passed by reference, value given in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\system\library\googleshopping\googleshopping.php on line 583
2023-03-09 15:40:57 - PHP Warning:  googleshopping\Googleshopping::integer(): Argument #1 ($product_id) must be passed by reference, value given in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\system\library\googleshopping\googleshopping.php on line 583
2023-03-09 15:40:58 - PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\admin\model\extension\advertise\google.php:341) in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\system\library\response.php on line 36
2023-03-10 9:33:28 - PHP Warning:  googleshopping\Googleshopping::integer(): Argument #1 ($product_id) must be passed by reference, value given in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\system\library\googleshopping\googleshopping.php on line 583
2023-03-10 9:33:28 - PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\admin\model\extension\advertise\google.php:341) in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\system\library\response.php on line 36
2023-03-10 12:42:29 - PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\admin\controller\marketplace\marketplace.php on line 1011
2023-03-10 12:42:29 - PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\startshop.ru\admin\controller\marketplace\marketplace.php on line 1013
2023-03-14 8:28:07 - PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\wamp64\cgi-bin\storage\vendor\scss.inc.php on line 1753
```

Please, sorry for my English and help me!

**UPD#1**

In the database, the path to the image looks like "catalog/products/StartLine_Game_Outdoor.png" which is correct, as I understand it

**UPD#2**

I installed OC-4.0.1.1 (rs.1). It's work, but why third version is not?...

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Comment: Image of code was upload to show different url in IMG-tag and in link address; illustration of non-obvious textual description of what preceded it